# How can I update a view (in node js) with a payload received from a webhook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, webhooks

I am working on an express js project. I configured a webhook and I am receiving it's post request on my index.js file. Now what I want is to update the index view with the received payload. I have tried res.render and even tried to redirect to another test view but it didn't work.
Is there a way to do it? Or do I have to store it to db and retrieve it again?
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet from my index.js file

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { message: 'Testing-initial'});
});

//capture webhooks
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    msgText = req.body.messages[0].text;
    console.log('meg received from channel' + msgText);    
    res.render('index', { message: msgText });   
});
```

following is my layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>...</title>
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</head>

<body class="alt-menu sidebar-noneoverflow">
    {{{body}}}

    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            App.init();
        });
    </script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/js/apps/mailbox-chat.js"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
</body>
</html>
```

I guess I don't have issues with it as I can GET the home with the text Testing-initial injected into it.

One last note: I have tried earlier to achieve this through WebSockets and it worked but I faced another issue which is missing payloads that come while there is no socket connection. Therefore, I am trying to do it without socket.io

Comment: Could you add some code please? :)

Comment: @andresmunozit just updated the question with a code snippet. I would really appreciate any help. I have been struggling with this issue for several days. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you. Let's see, is that console.log printing the message in the console?

Comment: Yes I am getting the message on the console

Comment: Could you please past the hbs template here :) and also, could you try adding const before msgText = req.body.messages[0].text

Comment: @andresmunozit  updated! and regarding the msgText it's already defined as a var (not shown in the snippet).Anyways I added const and still didn't work.

Comment: Could you please add the following line: "<p> {{message}} </p>", after {{{body}}}?

Comment: Do you have any "index.hbs" file?

Comment: Yes I do have index.hbs, and I have  {{message}} in it. and it's rendered perfectly with the initial value "Testing-initial". but doesn't update after the post from the webhook.